# Converting dates into a specific format in side a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, date, format

I am new to python and Iam trying to manipulate some data but it keeps showing me this erro message

```
 UserWarning: Parsing '13/01/2021' in DD/MM/YYYY format. Provide format or specify infer_datetime_format=True for consistent parsing.
  cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
```

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataLake = pd.read_csv("datalake - Data lake.csv", parse_dates=["Day"])
dataLake = dataLake.rename(columns={"Day":"day"})
dataLake = dataLake.rename(columns={"Agent":"agent"})

dataLake["day"] = pd.to_datetime(dataLake.day)
print(dataLake.head())
```

Comment: It is not an error just a warning letting you know that it is parsing dates using the following format: `dd/mm/yyyy` You should use the format param like the warning says `pd.to_datetime(dataLake.day, format='%m/%d/%Y')` The format for dates like `09/01/2021` is ambiguous without a format specified because is the date Sept. 1, 2021 or Jan. 9, 2021

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your case you need to set the dayfirst param to true, like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(dataLake.day, dayfirst=True)
```

or you can set a format (but you don't need to in your case), like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(dataLake.day, format="%d/%m/%y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we try to pass date without specifying the format, python tries to throw this warning.
You can follow 2 approaches.

1. Either pass a format for your date like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016], 'month': [2, 3],'day': [4, 5]})
pd.to_datetime(df)
```

2. Or just set `infer_datetime_format=True`, this is faster. Pandas will try to parse the columns into date format.

```
dt = pd.to_datetime("29/03/2023", infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: The infer_datetime_format=True will get this warning: UserWarning: The argument 'infer_datetime_format' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. A strict version of it is now the default, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pdeps/0004-consistent-to-datetime-parsing.html. You can safely remove this argument